# why [self.tableView reloadData] does not Work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

This is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row]; 
return cell;    
}
```

When i use `[self.tableView reloadData];` nothing happening?

Comment: Few Q?: is the class is of UITableViewController subclass? is array updated with new values before calling [self.tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to implement at least the [tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method as part of the UITableViewDataSource protocol, and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (which you already did). You should also implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Then you need to make sure that your class is actually used as a data source:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

That needs to be either done via Interface Builder or in `awakeFromNib` or some other method like `viewDidLoad:`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you check your dataSource and delegate of UITableView ? I think the dataSource is nil or something else.

Comment: Well, I assume you implement dataSource and delegate for UITableView, do you make sure your [self.tableView reloadData] has been called ? I assume that something did show when view appear. And, like Hanuman said, check your local data for dataSource being updated before reloadData.

Comment: i did all and when i add objects in viewDidload it shows but when i try to reload it its not work

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a break point in cell for row and see if it is called when u call reloadData. Also pls check if the changes are already made to array from which the cells are populated and make sure the table view is connected to its datasource and delegate.